# how to set value of button in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add button as per Model.total so how to set value of button dynamically?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.total; i++)
{
    <button id="btn" value="btn"> i.tostring() </button>
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question stating what is your expected result and what is your current result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    <button id="btn" value="btn"> @i.ToString() </button>
}
```

Comment: Great, please mark this as the answer if it's fixed your problem